# how to extract int from column where numbers are presented in brackets

Tags: python, pandas

```
bf['Films_Year']=bf['FILM'].apply(lambda var:var.split('(')[-1])
```

I get this output below

```
films(column name)

"
2015),
2015),
2015),
2015),
2015)
"
```

what should I do to get my year exactly?

Comment: Can `bf['FILM']` contain any other parentheses, e.g. in the movie name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.str.extract()` to get the integer part using a regular expression that matches the parenthesized year at the end.

```
bf['Films_Year']=bf['FILM'].str.extract(r'\((\d+)\)$')
```